# How can I stream video from an HDMI device over a local network?

Tags: hardware, hdmi, streaming, games, video-input

**The goal:**

To stream video and audio output from an HDMI device to a computer over a local network in real time. For example, streaming the HDMI output from an Xbox 360 to a computer on the same network. The computer would play the stream with VLC or a similar app.

**Questions:**

- Is this possible with a Raspberry Pi 3? Or is there another product that could do this more easily?
- Can the HDMI port on the Raspberry Pi 3 handle HDMI input? My understanding is it can't. If not, what additional hardware exists that could do that?
- Would the HDMI signal need to be processed or downsampled before streaming to reduce the data rate? If so, how? And is the Pi 3 fast enough to do that in real time?
- What kind of software setup on the Pi could do the streaming? Any OS is fine, ideally using Raspbian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you add an HDMI input device to a Raspberry Pi the complete setup becomes very expensive. Using off-the-shelf HDMI-over-IP devices is a better solution.

- ["Ludicrously cheap HDMI capture for Linux"](https://blog.benjojo.co.uk/post/cheap-hdmi-capture-for-linux)
- [Lekeng LKV373A](https://blog.danman.eu/new-version-of-lenkeng-hdmi-over-ip-extender-lkv373a/)
- [Discussion on hackernews](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11985261)

Comment: Thanks, the Lenkeng LKV373A looks interesting. The article mentions different sender and receiver types of units. I'm assuming I'd only need the sender one for my situation, right?

Comment: You would only need the sender. Note that those devices are rather simple and easily consume 97 Mbit/s of bandwidth. A Pi3 would be a good investment in such a case.

Comment: How are you thinking a Pi 3 could be used with a LKV373A sender? To reduce the bandwidth consumption somehow? The article on danman's blog mentions using URLs, a Windows app, or telnet to set the LKV373A's video bitrate, so I'd imagine that would help reduce it.